# Node express server stopped returning json object after being deployed on heroku

Tags: node.js, api, heroku, axios, request

I have this react-app that is connected to a node/express server. The node/express server all it has is app.get(api)

I connected it to 4 different apis, it gets the data and sends simply returns it to the front-end/client.

When I was building it and running it locally, it worked no problem. I would get the json objects and my front-end cleans the data and displays it. As soon as I deployed my server to heroku, it stopped working. I'm using axios to make the requests and I changed it from http://localhost/3000 to the url that heroku gave me. Now instead of getting my json data I get this error:

[image]

If it helps, when I run the url directly in my browser it works, I do see the data like I'm supposed to. Why is that? Thank you so much to whoever helps me!

As requested, this is a part of my express server, the other two routes are basically the same thing but of course to different APIs.

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();

// This enables our app (server 3000) to make requests
// can also do "*" to allow anyone to make them but not recommended
// for security reasons
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
  }),
);

app.get("/walmart/:item", (req, res) => {
  let url = `https://www.walmart.com/search/api/preso?prg=desktop&page=1&query=${req.params.item}`;

  var config = {
    method: "get",
    url: url,
    headers: {
      "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0",
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      wm_client_ip: "",
      Connection: "keep-alive",
      Cookie: process.env.WALMART_COOKIE,
      "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
      "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    },
  };

  axios(config)
    .then((response) => {
      res.send(response.data.items);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
});

app.get("/wholefoods/:item", (req, res) => {
  let url = `https://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/api/search?text=${req.params.item}&store=10152&limit=60&offset=0`;

  axios
    .get(url)
    .then((response) => {
      res.send(response.data.results);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
});
```

and this is the data I should be receiving when I call those routes from my react app (and the one I get when I use my browser at the moment)

[image]

Comment: could you tell us more? for example what does the Heroku version of your app return? and maybe some source code of your express app?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have edited my question and added a part of the express code and a picture of the data I'm expecting to receive. Like I said, that data is the one that the api returns to my express server and then express should send it to my react app. Everything was working and still works good on environment, but not when I make the request to Heroku, I am getting the first picture I shared here. Thank you!